# Merging MP3s with espeak, cat and PHP

Tags: php, bash, nginx, mp3, freebsd

I have a series of clips taken from a song, and also a couple of mp3s made by espeak via stdout.

Whenever I try to merge them (either using mp3wrap, or cat) I hear the whole thing but whenever there is one of those espeak mp3s, it just skips the playback as if theyre empty. I am able to play these files and the content is there. I have tried piping espeak's output to lame in order to encode them properly but this didnt work.

I am using PHP and nginx as this is all web based but I doubt it should have any effect on anything.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need to set --stdout argument for espeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *merge* a bunch of mp3, try doing :

```
sox files*.mp3 -t wavpcm - | lame - > bunch.mp3
```